# Change div style on button click within loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

So i'm using a While loop in PHP to return results from my database. Basically images with a button on each, when that button is clicked I want to display the mapOverlay div which will have a map on it. How do I select only the div that relates to the button i'm clicking? I can get it to open them all or just the first one but not the exact one with the button i'm click on.

This code sits within echo tags but i've removed to ease of reading:

```
<div class="resultContainer">
    <div class="mapOverlay animated slideInLeft"></div>
    <div class="resultsInfo">
        <div class='resultsInfo_user'>
            <div class='results_dp' style='background-image:url($row[dp])'></div>
            <p style='color:#565656;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;float: left;font-weight:600'>ucfirst($row[firstName])</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='resultsImage' style='background-image: url($row[image])'>
        <div class='resultsImage_overlay'>
            <div class='resultsImage_overlay_info'>
                <p style='font-size:1.1em;font-weight:600;color:#4A4A4A;margin:0'>$row[title]</p>
                <p style='margin: 5px 0px 1px 0px;font-size:0.9em;color:#828282'>$distanceMiles</p>
                <p style='margin:0;font-size:0.9em;color:#828282'>$row[expiry]</p>
            </div>
            <div class='resultsImage_overlay_button'>
                <button class='button-green openMap'>Get Directions</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the javascript I've got:

```
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("openMap")

for(var i = 0; i < button.length; i++){
    button[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        var overlay = document.getElementsByClassName("mapOverlay")

        overlay.style.display = "block"
    })
}
```

I'm going to toggle a class when I get it working but just using style.display to get it working first for ease of testing. I also want resultsImage_overlay to display above the overlay so the button remains visible / able to close the div overlay again.

I'm looking to be pointed in the right direction here, complete solutions welcome but I appreciate I haven't provided all the blocks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with [**`closest()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) and [**`previousElementSibling`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling) on [**`this`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) object.

**Demo:**

```js
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("openMap")
  for(var i = 0; i < button.length; i++){
  button[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    var overlay = this.closest('.resultsImage').previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling;
    overlay.style.display = "block"
  })
}
```

```css
.mapOverlay {display: none}
```

```html
<div class="resultContainer">
    <div class="mapOverlay animated slideInLeft">mapOverlay 1</div>
    <div class="resultsInfo">
        <div class='resultsInfo_user'>
            <div class='results_dp' style='background-image:url($row[dp])'></div>
            <p style='color:#565656;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;float: left;font-weight:600'>John</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='resultsImage' style='background-image: url($row[image])'>
        <div class='resultsImage_overlay'>
            <div class='resultsImage_overlay_info'>
                <p style='font-size:1.1em;font-weight:600;color:#4A4A4A;margin:0'>Some Title</p>
                <p style='margin: 5px 0px 1px 0px;font-size:0.9em;color:#828282'>50</p>
                <p style='margin:0;font-size:0.9em;color:#828282'>12-12-2020</p>
            </div>
            <div class='resultsImage_overlay_button'>
                <button class='button-green openMap'>Get Directions</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="mapOverlay animated slideInLeft">mapOverlay 2</div>
    <div class="resultsInfo">
        <div class='resultsInfo_user'>
            <div class='results_dp' style='background-image:url($row[dp])'></div>
            <p style='color:#565656;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;float: left;font-weight:600'>Michael</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='resultsImage' style='background-image: url($row[image])'>
        <div class='resultsImage_overlay'>
            <div class='resultsImage_overlay_info'>
                <p style='font-size:1.1em;font-weight:600;color:#4A4A4A;margin:0'>Some Title 2</p>
                <p style='margin: 5px 0px 1px 0px;font-size:0.9em;color:#828282'>40</p>
                <p style='margin:0;font-size:0.9em;color:#828282'>11-11-2020</p>
            </div>
            <div class='resultsImage_overlay_button'>
                <button class='button-green openMap'>Get Directions</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```